# Select text / set focus in textInput

Tags: r, shiny

**Background**

In my app I have a login page with a `textInput` for the user name, a `passwordInput` for the password and an `actionButton` for submitting. If the password/username is not recognised, I show an error message. So far so good. I just want now to programatically select/highlight all the text in the username `textInput`, if the login did not work.

**Question**

How can I select the text in the username input form? I looked at `updateTextInput` but with this I can only change the value, not the selection. Do I need to fall back to javascript?

**Code**

```
library(shiny)

is_valid_user <- function(uid, pwd) {
   FALSE
}

ui <- fluidPage(
   textInput("uid", "Username:"),
   passwordInput("pwd", "Password"),
   actionButton("ok", "Login"),
   div(textOutput("error"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$ok, {
                 if (!is_valid_user(req(input$uid), req(input$pwd))) {
                    output$error <- renderText("Username/password incorrect!")
                    ## TODO: select all text in textInput("uid"), but HOW?
                 }})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi I think there is no way to do in in pure Shiny. If you're willing to use a bit of JS here's a simple example that sends and handles custom message from Shiny to JS ([more here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html)). It essentially only selects text in the input but once you're on the JS side, you can do basically anything you want. Cheers!

```
library(shiny)

is_valid_user <- function(uid, pwd) {
  FALSE
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script("
      Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('selectText', function(message) {
        $('#uid').select();
      });
    ")
  ),
  textInput("uid", "Username:"),
  passwordInput("pwd", "Password"),
  actionButton("ok", "Login"),
  div(textOutput("error"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$ok, {
    if (!is_valid_user(req(input$uid), req(input$pwd))) {
      output$error <- renderText("Username/password incorrect!")
      ## TODO: select all text in textInput("uid"), but HOW?
      session$sendCustomMessage("selectText", "select")
    }})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(port = 5555))
```

Comment: Perfect, that was what I was looking for. Thanks + 1